# Android ExpandableListView getChildView makes a mess of data

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-viewholder

I'm trying to learn Android and java and I'm running into difficulty with ExpandableListViews.

I am trying to make an Expandablelistview that has a number of editTexts and textViews underneath it. I could have anywhere from 1 to 20 groups and each group has 3 editTexts and a textView.

I want to populate the data from database on start up and as the users modify the data, save it back. I tried to do it but the data seems to be ALL over the place. Simple test:

- Add 3 groups, 1 child each
- add data to each editText
- Collapse all groups and expand them last one to first one

-> result is that group 1 and 2 will have identical data as the last group!!! It's driving me crazy! Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong, please?

This is my getChildView, which is very very simple.

```
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    if (convertView == null) {
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        Log.i("Main", "Creating new viewHolder for " + groupPosition+childPosition);
        convertView = minflater.inflate(R.layout.childrow, null);

        holder.text1 = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rpsinSet);
        holder.text2 = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.wtForSet);
        holder.text3 = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rstForSet);
        holder.No    = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.NoTextView);

        holder.No.setText("Set " + (childPosition + 1));
        holder.text1.setText(""+Sets.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition).getRps());
        holder.text2.setText(""+Sets.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition).getWt());
        holder.text3.setText(""+Sets.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition).getRst());


        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        Log.i("Main", "Recovering viewHolder for " + groupPosition+childPosition);
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        holder.text1   = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rpsinSet);
        holder.text2   = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.wtForSet);
        holder.text3   = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rstForSet);
        holder.No      = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.NoTextView);
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

This is my ViewHolder:

```
static class ViewHolder {
    EditText text1;
    EditText text2;
    EditText text3;
    TextView No;
}
```

I did not add the database calls because they are irrelevant. I can't even get this to work right now.

Comment: you don't set your view in `else` statement, you must set it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to post this as a comment but I don't have enough reputation. Anyway I'll try NOT to check if convertView is null , but I'll always recreate it, because every time you expand or close a group the list gets recreated, and maybe it's reusing the same view for every cell, and that's probably the cause of you having the same data in different lines.

Comment: Great point. I was doing what you just suggested here before moving on to this. The reason I moved on to this way of doing was because I was not able to get TextWatcher working at all, and I read somewhere that this would be the better way of doing it but apparently I cannot get it to work. I'll try again and update on my progress. I may have to get you guys' help on TextWatcher if this works otherwise.